# htaccess rewrite rule to hide controller

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

That is my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rt=$1 [L,QSA]
```

It recognizes which controller should be open (MVC-my own framework)
so `domain.com/about` goes to `aboutController`

And when the address is `domain.com/prod/category/product` I want the address to be
`domain.com/category/product` to hide controller.

Is it possible?

I want that rule just for `domain.com/prod` and `domain.com/cat`

Answer (score 1):

Easy, just set a `RewriteCond` for `prod` and `cat` like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(prod|cat)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rt=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: you can click on link and you can see prod is still there

Comment: and do you know how to change /index.php?rt=prod/cat/cola to /cat/prod